# How to resolve Shared Preferences not initialized error: Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, rest, sharedpreferences, statefulwidget

**Scenario:** I have a page with a ListView which shows a list of several items from the database, fetched using a REST API. I am loading the data in the **initState() method**. In order to load the data, I also need some data stored in the Shared Preferences. I obtain the instance of shared preferences before loading the data and rendering the UI. The UI changes based on the AccountType stored in the **Shared Preferences**.
**Problem:** When I navigate to the specific page in the app, I get an error-

```
LateInitializationError: Field '_sharedPreferences@53458703' has not been initialized.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  QuizListPage QuizListPage:file:///D:/Github_Work/Assessment%20Portal/assessmentportal/lib/Pages/CategoryTile.dart:27:41
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _QuizListPageState._sharedPreferences (package:assessmentportal/Pages/QuizListPage.dart)
#1      _QuizListPageState.build (package:assessmentportal/Pages/QuizListPage.dart:72:19)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5041:11)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
...     Normal element mounting (275 frames)
```

My code is-

```
class QuizListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  CategoryModel category;

  QuizListPage({required this.category});

  @override
  State<QuizListPage> createState() => _QuizListPageState();
}

class _QuizListPageState extends State<QuizListPage> {
  late SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;
  List<QuizModel> quizzes = [];
  late CategoryService _categoryService;
  bool _areQuizzesLoaded = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeData();
  }

  void _initializeData() async {
    _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _categoryService = CategoryService();
    setState(() {
      _areQuizzesLoaded = false;
    });
    await _loadCategories();
  }

  Future<void> _loadCategories() async {
    if (_sharedPreferences.getString(ROLE) == ROLE_NORMAL) {
      quizzes = await _categoryService.getAllQuizzesByCategory(
          _sharedPreferences.getString(BEARER_TOKEN) ?? 'null',
          widget.category.categoryId);
    } else {
      quizzes = await _categoryService.getAllQuizzesByAdminAndCategory(
        adminid: _sharedPreferences.getInt(USER_ID) ?? 0,
        categoryid: widget.category.categoryId,
        token: _sharedPreferences.getString(BEARER_TOKEN) ?? 'null',
      );
    }
    setState(() {
      log('Setting loaded to true');
      _areQuizzesLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        AppBar().preferredSize.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.category.categoryTitle),
        actions: (_sharedPreferences.getString(ROLE) != ROLE_NORMAL)
            ? [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10,
                    right: 10,
                    left: 5,
                    bottom: 5,
                  ),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AddQuizPage(
                            userid: _sharedPreferences.getInt(USER_ID) ?? 0,
                            categoryid: widget.category.categoryId ?? 0,
                            token: _sharedPreferences.getString(BEARER_TOKEN) ??
                                'null',
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text('Add Quiz'),
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            : null,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child:Text('Hello'),
           ),
         );
        }
   }
```

Please help me understand why this error occurs (sometimes not always) and **what is the correct way to load data before showing the UI (Some UI components depend on the data
stored in shared preferences)**, I want to use Shared Preferences, the way its used in my code. Please help!

Comment: You could use `Future<SharedPreferences>` in combination with `FutureBuilder`.
Have a look at [https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify it to the following code:

```dart
bool _spInitOK = false;

void _initializeData() async {
  _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    _spInitOK = true;
  });
  ...
}

actions: !_spInitOK
    ? null
    : (_sharedPreferences.getString(ROLE) != ROLE_NORMAL)
        ? [...
```

The following is my understanding:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  debugPrint("[${DateTime.now()}] _initializeData before");
  _initializeData();
  debugPrint("[${DateTime.now()}] _initializeData after");
}

void _initializeData() async {
  debugPrint("[${DateTime.now()}] _initializeData start");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // await 2s
  _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    _spInitOK = true;
  });
  ...
  debugPrint("[${DateTime.now()}] _initializeData end");
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrint("[${DateTime.now()}] build");
  ...
}
```

```dart
I/flutter (26518): [2022-11-25 01:03:52.868143] _initializeData before
I/flutter (26518): [2022-11-25 01:03:52.878696] _initializeData start
I/flutter (26518): [2022-11-25 01:03:52.881150] _initializeData after
I/flutter (26518): [2022-11-25 01:03:52.887225] build // first build, _sharedPreferences is null in this moment, so can't use it
// 2s
I/flutter (26518): [2022-11-25 01:03:54.896708] _initializeData end
I/flutter (26518): [2022-11-25 01:03:54.904256] build // second build
```